# Why do I get HTTP 404 when there's no .asmx extension?

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows, iis

I'm trying to write an HTTP GET handler. The path should start with `http://site/processTask` and have a set of URL-encoded parameters. I have the following in my web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    <add verb="GET" path="processTask*" type="MyHandler.ProcessTaskHandler, MyHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

now when I type the URL `http://mysite/processTask` in browser I get HTTP 404 but if I change the `add verb` line to the following one:

```
<add verb="GET" path="processTask.asmx*" type="MyHandler.ProcessTaskHandler, MyHandler"/>
```

and type `http://mysite/ProcessTask.asmx` in browser the handler is run and I get the response from the handler.

What's the problem? Why is the handler run only when the path contains `.asmx`? How do I change `web.config` so that `.asmx` is not required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a path is just **/processTask** (no extension) IIS **can not understand first of all that it has to pass the request to ASP.NET** especially on IIS 5.1, and the file is not being processed by ASP.NET but just served from disk (and there's no such file, hence HTTP 404).

To be able to do that you need to set IIS to process all files with ASP.NET

On IIS 5.1, right click on the root, open Web Site Properties | Home Directory | Configuration, and there copy/paste settings from `*.aspx` (or any other extension that is already handled by ASP.NET) to a new extension as `.*` and uncheck "Verify file exists" checkbox there. [Here's a step-by-step guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx) for a similar problem.

Comment: That seems to not work - I don't have `.` in the path and the page you mention won't let me leave the "extension" field blank.

Comment: @sharptooth I have update the answer, the issue here is to make all request to iis, to process from asp.net

Comment: Okay, the key is that first, extension must be specified as `.*` *and* "check file exists" must be unchecked - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx

Comment: @shaptooth oh, you make it work ? good, please update my answer if you like to the right steps.