# How do I pass requests to URLs without extension to ASP.NET on IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-services, iis, iis-6

I want my ASP.NET HTTP handler to be invoked when a user opens an URL of this format:

```
http://mySite/getStuff?id="actualId"
```

In order to do that on IIS5.1 I had to open the IIS management console and [map `.*` extension onto ASP.NET ISAPI handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419728/why-do-i-get-http-404-when-theres-no-asmx-extension/5419841#5419841) so that the request is processed using ASP.NET in the first place.

Turns out IIS6 console won't accept `.*` as a valid extension.

I know there's such thing as URL rewrite, but I feel it's an overkill for such simple case.

Are there some easier ways to pass all requests to URLs that don't have an extension to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try having wildcard mapping but with lowest priority, so all above it will be mapped to their proper ISAPI. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true